# Externalize a property file which is inside a jar file

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have jar with application.properties file as below-

```
BASE_ENVIRONMENT = http://localhost
```

This is my utility class to read the property file

```
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream(fileName + ".properties");
```

the property file is in `<default package>`

This jar is used as a dependent jar in my web application which is deployed in `tomcat server`.

But i need to change the `BASE_ENVIRONMENT` for production environment.

Is there a way i can externalize this property file value?

Comment: Perhaps something similar to [Spring Boot's approach](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).  Basically, the file within the jar defines default values while the external file overrides 1 or more of the default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a system parameter to act as a profile:

```
 // default to DEV
 String profile = "dev"
 if (System.getProperty("ENV") != null) {
    profile = System.getProperty("ENV");
 }
 Properties prop = new Properties();
 ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
 InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream(fileName + "_" + profile + ".properties");
```

Then you would start your app with

```
   .... -DENV=prod
```

and the file like config_prod.properties would be found in the classpath, the default would be config_dev.properties.